# Multiple groups with mongodb aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, grouping, aggregate

I'm trying to use `mongoDb` aggregate on this data:

```
"_id": ObjectId("598dbd301ab6476e5b15e05e"),
"updated_at": ISODate("2017-08-11T14:20:32.865Z"),
"created_at": ISODate("2017-08-11T14:20:32.865Z"),
"action": ObjectId("59760749a398cb323cf1c051"),
"subAction": ObjectId("5980c3807a8cb300110d87d3"),
"person": ObjectId("598dbd2f1ab6476e5b15e05b"),
"session": ObjectId("598dbd2f1ab6476e5b15e05c"),
"dateAccomplish": ISODate("2017-08-11T14:20:32Z"),
"createdBy": ObjectId("595f8426645bf5f47366fb29"),
"updatedBy": ObjectId("595f8426645bf5f47366fb29"),
```

What I'm trying to do is that I need to retrieve 2 groups. It has to be grouped by `actions` and `subactions`.

The output data expected looks like this:

```
movactions: [
{
     _id: $created_at,
     count: ?,
     data:[
         {
             _id: "$action",
             count: 3,
             data: [
                {
                    _id: "$subaction",
                    count: 2
                }
             ]
          }
     ]
},
]
```

there are many subActions that have an action, i want to aggregate each action with their children subactions listed

Comment: so what you have tried?

Comment: I could group by actions but have no clue on how to group the matched actions with its subactions

Comment: with compound keys https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-month-day-and-year ?

Comment: can you show me an example? i dont think i understanded what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group by multiple fields, [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-month-day-and-year) should be applied multiple times with compound `_id`, gradually reducing it in each next group:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id:{created_at:"$created_at", action:"$action", subAction:"$subAction"},
        count: {$sum:1}
    }},
    {$group:{
        _id:{created_at:"$_id.created_at", action:"$_id.action"},
        count: {$sum:1},
        data: {$push:{_id: "$_id.subAction", count:"$count"}}
    }},
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id.created_at",
        count: {$sum:1},
        data: {$push:{_id: "$_id.action", count:"$count", data:"$data"}}
    }}, 
    {$project: {
        _id:0,
        created_at:"$_id", 
        count:1, 
        data:1
    }}
]);
```

Comment: kinda like this, but i have many subActions that has an action, i want to grab the subActions inside the actions it belongs to

Comment: hmm, so what's the problem? `data` within `action` should contain all `subActions` that has common `created_at` and `action`.

Comment: they have different `created_at` dates. How do you expect `_id: $created_at,` grouping to work then?